# Fetch data into an array of objects according to another array

Tags: javascript, arrays, underscore.js

This code compares the first array names to see if there is duplicates, once the duplicates are found, these duplicates are compared to 2 others array created by pl and pl2, if duplicates are found between the original duplicates and pl or pl2, these new duplicates are showed in the console.

```
var names = ["Nancy", "Patrick", "George", "Hecker", "George", "Nancy", 
"Robert", "Robert"]

var part1 = [
{height : 1.2, weight : 50, age: 55, name : "Nancy" },
{height : 2, weight : 60, age: 47, name : "Patrick" },
{height : 2, weight : 42, age: 24, name : "George" },
{height : 1.7, weight : 56, age: 58, name : "Hecker" },
{height : 1.1, weight : 39, age: 23, name : "Karin" }
]

var part2 = [
{height : 0.2, weight : 23, age: 45, name : "George" },
{height : 1.8, weight : 41, age: 29, name : "Moos" },
{height : 1.5, weight : 35, age: 25, name : "Ricard" }
]

setTimeout(function() {
var uniq = names
.map((name) => {
return {count: 1, name: name}
})
.reduce((a, b) => {
a[b.name] = (a[b.name] || 0) + b.count
return a
}, {})

var duplicates = Object.keys(uniq).filter((a) => uniq[a] > 1)

console.log(duplicates) //output array with Nancy and George

checkInArr(duplicates);

}, 500);

function checkInArr(duplicates) {

var pl = _.pluck(part1, "name");
var pl2 = _.pluck(part2, "name");
var dup = _.intersection(pl, duplicates);
var dup2 = _.intersection(pl2, duplicates);

dup.forEach(function(element) {
console.log(element)

//Here is where I'm stuck, element regroup the name that are the same in 
both duplicates and part1
//Now I would like to fetch the other corresponding data in the part1 and 
part2 arrays of objects according to the names returned by element
//in this exemple : element returns Nancy and George so i would like to get 
Nancy and George infos of part1 (height, weight, age)

})

dup2.forEach(function(element) {
console.log(element)

//in this exemple : element returns only George so i would like to get 
George infos of part2 (height, weight, age)

})
}
```

But, as it is written inside the code, I would like to get the full infos according to the name and both arrays in the console.

So the wanted result would be the object of the corresponding names and not just the names. For exemple : if element returns George, I would like not only the name but all the infos about George stored in part1 and then another object of all the infos about George stored in part2.

I've tried some things but with no success and also didn't found infos on the web.
Thanks for helping.

**Fiddle** : http://jsfiddle.net/nc2ac8ed/

Comment: please add the wanted result as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could change your `checkInArr` function to use a `Set` and `filter` to check the intersections.

Your `duplicates` is an array of names that you're interested in. By creating a `Set` out of those values we can quickly check if a "person" intersects:

```
const doesIntersect = nameSet.has(person.name);
```

This can be used in a `filter` to weed out the non-duplicates.

```js
var names = ["Nancy", "Patrick", "George", "Hecker", "George", "Nancy", "Robert", "Robert"]

var part1=[{height:1.2,weight:50,age:55,name:"Nancy"},{height:2,weight:60,age:47,name:"Patrick"},{height:2,weight:42,age:24,name:"George"},{height:1.7,weight:56,age:58,name:"Hecker"},{height:1.1,weight:39,age:23,name:"Karin"}];
var part2=[{height:.2,weight:23,age:45,name:"George"},{height:1.8,weight:41,age:29,name:"Moos"},{height:1.5,weight:35,age:25,name:"Ricard"}];

var uniq = names
  .map((name) => {
    return {count: 1, name: name}
  })
  .reduce((a, b) => {
    a[b.name] = (a[b.name] || 0) + b.count
    return a
  }, {})

var duplicates = Object.keys(uniq).filter((a) => uniq[a] > 1)

console.log(duplicates) //output array with Nancy and George *and Robert*

checkInArr(duplicates);


function checkInArr(duplicates) {
  const dupSet = new Set(duplicates);
  const dup = part1.filter(p => dupSet.has(p.name));
  const dup2 = part2.filter(p => dupSet.has(p.name));

  dup.forEach(function(element) {
    console.log("dup", element)

  })

  dup2.forEach(function(element) {
    console.log("dup2:", element)

  })
}
```